# Difficulty speeding up pytorch code: training a MLP using a complicated many-to-one nonlinear function

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, vectorization, perceptron

**In short:**

**My goal is to figure out if a specific complicated nonlinear function can be used to replace individual neurons in a neural network. Ideally, I'd like to show that I can train on MNIST pictures of numbers. I've made an attempt in pytorch, but it is way too slow, mostly because I haven't been able to figure out how to do batches and neurons in parallel, and I'm looking for ideas or approaches to be able to dramatically speed up the process.**

A typical neuron in a neural network is defined as performing a dot-product and then performing a nonlinear function on the output of that dot product, f(x dot w).

Instead of f(x dot w), I am considering a many-to-one nonlinear function that is a more general nonlinear function of x and w, i.e. f(x, w). The nonlinear function f(x, w) takes a 1D array of X and a 1D array of W, and returns a single output. I have numpy code which performs this calculation. It models a real physical system and requires a recursive series of integrals to calculate. In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76875869/pytorch-back-propagation-of-custom-many-to-one-nonlinearity), I learned that I can convert my numpy code to pytorch functions and that pytorch should be able to automatically do the back-propagation gradents for me.

Now I have pytorch code describing the nonlinear function f(x,w). I want to demonstrate that I can use it to learn on pictures of numbers, and so I have reduced MNIST numbers to 10x10 pixel images and have set up a MLP-inspired network with 100 inputs, a hidden size of 100, and 10 outputs.

*Explaining this MLP-inspired network in greater detail:*

The first layer consists of 100 "neurons" where the typical neuron is replaced with my nonlinear function f(x, w). Each of the 100 "neurons" accepts the input for X and has a different set of weights w. Finally, the outputs of these 100 neurons are passed on to the next layer. The next layer is simply 10 neurons, the output of each are used for identifying each of the 10 digits.

Here is a snippet of the code for the forward pass of the network:

```
class MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_classes):
        super(MLP, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.weights1 = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(input_size, hidden_size))  # weights of size (input_size, hidden_size)
        self.weights2 = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(hidden_size, num_classes)) # weights of size (hidden_size, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        hidden_outputs = []
        for neuron_weights in self.weights1.T:  # loop over each neuron's weights in the first layer
            output_value = input_output_nonlinearity_torch(x.squeeze(), neuron_weights, C_total = C_total, readoutStrength = readoutStrength)
            output_value = F.relu(output_value)  # apply a relu activation function
            hidden_outputs.append(output_value)

       final_outputs = []
       for neuron_weights in self.weights2.T:  # loop over each neuron's weights in the second layer
           output_value = input_output_nonlinearity_torch(hidden_outputs, neuron_weights, C_total = C_total, readoutStrength = readoutStrength)
           final_outputs.append(output_value)

       final_outputs = [output.unsqueeze(0) for output in final_outputs]
       final_output = torch.stack(final_outputs, dim=0)
       final_output = final_output.t()
       return final_output
```

The problem is that each iteration of training this network takes about 20 minutes for just a single feed-forward pass of a single number for training. So, I really need to figure out how to make this faster.

input_output_nonlinearity() is my nonlinear function f(x, w). As you can see from the code, I am finding the output of each "neuron" in the network individually, by for-looping through each of the weights. In principle, though, each neuron is fully independent, and could be run in parallel.

So, one approach would be to further vectorize my code. But, I have not been able to figure out a simple vectorized way that I could pass a matrix X and a matrix W to f(x, w), such that I get a set of outputs for different neurons and sets of input data (and I'll give the full code at the end). This to me seems to be fairly challenging to implement (but I'm sure is possible).

Another idea is that maybe there's another way of telling pytorch that these calculations are completely independent, so it can do some parallel processing under the hood? Any ideas if that is possible, or do I have to brute-force my way via a fully vectorized solution?

Here is the code for the whole thing. My apologies for the length, but I want to give the full code so that any speed inefficiencies can be properly identified.

Here is the code for the training of the network:

```
from neural_network_pytorch_dot_product import *
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torch.utils.data as data
import numpy
import torch.nn.functional as F

numpoints_for_greens_integrals = 100
C_total = .1
readoutStrength = 1/C_total

def reduce_dataset(dataloader, fraction):
    num_samples = int(len(dataloader.dataset) * fraction)
    indices = torch.randperm(len(dataloader.dataset))[:num_samples]
    new_dataset = data.Subset(dataloader.dataset, indices)
    new_dataloader = data.DataLoader(new_dataset, batch_size=dataloader.batch_size, shuffle=True)
    return new_dataloader


class MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_classes):
        super(MLP, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.weights1 = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(input_size, hidden_size))  # weights of size (input_size, hidden_size)
        self.weights2 = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(hidden_size, num_classes)) # weights of size (hidden_size, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        hidden_outputs = []
        for neuron_weights in self.weights1.T:  # loop over each neuron's weights in the first layer
            output_value = input_output_nonlinearity_torch(x.squeeze(), neuron_weights, C_total = C_total, readoutStrength = readoutStrength)
            output_value = F.relu(output_value)  # apply a relu activation function
            hidden_outputs.append(output_value)

        final_outputs = []
        for neuron_weights in self.weights2.T:  # loop over each neuron's weights in the second layer
            output_value = input_output_nonlinearity_torch(hidden_outputs, neuron_weights, C_total = C_total, readoutStrength = readoutStrength)
            final_outputs.append(output_value)

        final_outputs = [output.unsqueeze(0) for output in final_outputs]
        final_output = torch.stack(final_outputs, dim=0)
        final_output = final_output.t()
        return final_output

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

# hyperparameters

input_size = 100
hidden_size = 100
num_classes = 10
num_epochs = 10
batch_size = 1
learning_rate = 0.001

pixelX = 10

# MNIST dataset (28x28 images!)
# train_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor(), download=True)
# test_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=False, transform=transforms.ToTensor())

# Compressed images to (10x10 images!)
# Define a new transform to resize the images
resize_transform = transforms.Resize((10, 10))

# MNIST dataset with resize transform
train_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=True, transform=transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    resize_transform
]), download=True)

test_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=False, transform=transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    resize_transform
]))


train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

# Update train loader and test loader
train_loader = reduce_dataset(train_loader, 0.01) # reduce to 1% of original size
test_loader = reduce_dataset(test_loader, 0.01) # reduce to 1% of original size


# instantiate the MLP
model = MLP(input_size, hidden_size, num_classes).to(device)

# loss and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)


# train the model
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        images = images.reshape(-1, pixelX*pixelX).to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)
        
        # forward pass
        print('beginning forward pass')
        outputs = model(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        
        # backward and optimize
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss.item()
    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}, Loss: {running_loss/len(train_loader)}")

# test the model
with torch.no_grad():
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    for images, labels in test_loader:
        images = images.reshape(-1, pixelX*pixelX).to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)
        outputs = model(images)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

    print('Accuracy of the network on test images: {} %'.format(100 * correct / total))
```

And here is the code describing the nonlinear function f(x, w):

```
import torch
from torch import nn, optim
import numpy as np
from scipy import special

def readinKernel_torch(wdummy, z, Ec, Ep, kval=1, ic = 10**-9*torch.sqrt(3.14/(8*torch.log(torch.tensor([2.]))))*2*3.14*3*10**6, od = 10000, gamma = 2*3.14*18*10**9/(2*3.14*3*10**6), extra = 1, Np = (8*torch.log(torch.tensor([2.]))/(torch.pow(torch.tensor([10.])**-9*(2*3.14*3*10**6),2)*torch.tensor(torch.pi))).pow(0.25)):
    return Ec * kval * torch.special.bessel_j0(2* Ec * kval * torch.sqrt(torch.ger(z, (1 - wdummy))))*torch.exp(-1*1j*Ec**2*extra*repmat_torch(wdummy, len(z))*kval**2*gamma/od)* torch.sqrt(ic)*Ep*Np

def readoutKernel_torch(zdummy, z, B_in, Ec, kval=1):
    return  (Ec * kval *
            steep_sigmoid_torch(torch.sub(z.repeat(zdummy.size(0), 1).T, zdummy), 50) *
            1 / torch.sqrt(torch.clamp(torch.sub(z.repeat(zdummy.size(0), 1).T, zdummy), min=1e-10)) *
            torch.special.bessel_j1(2 * Ec * kval * torch.sqrt(torch.clamp(torch.sub(z.repeat(zdummy.size(0), 1).T, zdummy), min=1e-10))) *
            repmat_torch(B_in, len(z)))

def final_readoutKernel_torch(zdummy, w, Ec, B_in, kval=1):
    #  This is the same Kernel as the readin kernel, but with K(z, w) switched to K(w, z).    
    out = Ec * kval * torch.special.bessel_j0(2* Ec * kval * torch.sqrt(torch.ger(w, (1 - zdummy))))*repmat_torch(B_in, len(w))
    return out

def repmat_torch(arr, num_reps):
    return arr.view(1, -1).repeat(num_reps, 1)

def steep_sigmoid_torch(x, k=50):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + torch.exp(-k*x))

def complex_trap_torch(z, xvals, axisdim):
    real_values = torch.real(z)
    imaginary_values = torch.imag(z)
    real_integral = torch.trapz(real_values, x=xvals, dim=axisdim)
    imaginary_integral = torch.trapz(imaginary_values, x=xvals, dim=axisdim)
    complexout = real_integral + 1j * imaginary_integral
    return complexout

def spinwave_recursive_calculation_torch(B_in, z_values, w_values, Ec, Ep, c_per_mode = 1):

    readin_values = readinKernel_torch(w_values, z_values, Ec, Ep, kval = c_per_mode)
    readout_values = readoutKernel_torch(z_values, z_values, B_in, Ec, kval = c_per_mode)

    readin_integrals = complex_trap_torch(readin_values, xvals=w_values, axisdim=1)
    readout_integrals = complex_trap_torch(readout_values, xvals=z_values, axisdim=1) 

    spinwave = readin_integrals - readout_integrals + B_in
    return spinwave



def input_output_nonlinearity_torch(x, w, numpoints = 100, C_total = 1, readoutStrength = 1):
    z_values =  torch.linspace(1e-10, 1-1e-10, numpoints)
    w_values =  torch.linspace(1e-10, 1-1e-10, numpoints)

    Bin = torch.zeros(len(z_values), dtype=torch.complex128)
    BoutMatrix = repmat_torch(Bin, len(w))

    c_per_mode = C_total/len(w)

    for i in range(len(w)):
        E_c_val = w[i]
        E_p_val = x[i]
        # print('E_p_val', E_p_val)
        # print('x', x)
        BoutMatrix[i, :] = spinwave_recursive_calculation_torch(Bin, z_values, w_values, E_c_val, E_p_val, c_per_mode)
        Bin = BoutMatrix[i, :]
    Bout = BoutMatrix[-1, :]

    output_Efield_w_z = final_readoutKernel_torch(z_values, w_values, readoutStrength, Bout, kval=1)
    output_Efield_w = torch.trapz(torch.real(output_Efield_w_z), x = z_values, dim =1)
    output_Efield = torch.trapz(torch.real(output_Efield_w), x = w_values, dim = 0)

    return output_Efield
```

(Again, apologies for the long code, but the key difficulty of my problem is exactly that it's hard to vectorize such a complicated thing. If I tried writing a simpler example, then it likely will be more clear how to vectorize it and a User's answer to that simplified question won't help me.)

Comment: In general, people usually use neural networks made of trainable linear layers, and nonlinear transfer functions with a simple derivative. Unless you have some reason to think that a change of representation is helpful, you're probably better off with a simple transfer function and a large number of layers than you are with a complicated transfer function and a small number of layers.

Comment: @NickODell, yes I am well aware of that and I have a specific reason for considering this system.

Comment: Is it acceptable for you to limit the batch size to 1?
Also, does it have to be solved using PyTorch?

Comment: @YakovDan, the only reason why the batch size is 1 is because I couldn't figure out how to write my nonlinear function in a way to process more than one input at a time. Processing multiple batches at the same time would be very useful. Also, I chose pytorch because it is easy to use, but it is not a requirement for me to use pytorch.

Comment: I think the problem is not that the function is slow, but the for loop is gigantic. Your inner function runs 100.000.000 for each pass... Did I read your code right? 2 for loops with neuron_weights being 100 x 100 = 10.000

Comment: @JulianoNegri, yup, you read it correctly. I tried to make it clear that this is what I believe to be the problem as well.  My question is if I have to force my function to handle a vectorized solution or if there is an easier method. (like numpa, for example)

Comment: @JulianoNegri, also, there are 100 neurons in 2 layers, but that doesnt make it 100 x 100 but 200.  You are correct that there is a multiplicative slowdown but that's between the inputs X and weights W. Additionally, I should mention that I used some simple example of an MLP on pictures of numbers, and significantly reduced the size of the space for my example. (it was previously 780 by 500 for the neurons, and images that are 24x24 with 70000 pictures of numbers. Now its 100 by 100, with 10x10 images and 700 pictures of numbers)